# Is it possible to point out to a recruiter his problematic manners?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment

Once I had an interview at a company for a job with the boss.

Everything was great but there was only one thing that made me choose an other company for a nearly identical offer : the man kept picking his nose during a big part of the interview.

It wouldn't be such a problem if courtesy didn't make handshake a part of greetings.

If I encounter such situation again I'd like to politely express and explain my bother to him. But it is even possible?

If yes, what could a good approach for this be?

Comment: I feel the answer is, it is not possible.  (It's also fairly unlikely it will come up again? :)  )

Comment: @Fattie Sadly that's the answer I was fearing yet expecting. However It's likely to happen again : I might get interviewed for this job again nearly one year after.

Comment: You get another job, awesome! **Now let it go.**

Comment: There are more than two companies to apply to, let it go.

Comment: The polite thing to do when someone makes a faux pas is to ignore it.  anything else is boorish.

Comment: @RichardU So I should just don't mind and shake his hand anyway?

Comment: Either shake his hand and then go wash up discreetly, or use one of these strategies: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/how-to-refuse-to-shake-hands-without-offending-the-other-party

Comment: @vmonteco  There's a legend about Queen Victoria entertaining a foreign dignitary who had never seen a fingerbowl, and drank from it.  Not wanting him to lose face, she did the same.  Yes, you shake his hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I encounter such situation again I'd like to politely express and explain my bother to him. But it is even possible?

No.

You might be able to avoid shaking hands by gesturing with some other kind of greeting (though even that could be taken as a bit *odd*), but you're not going to find a polite way of saying "I'm not shaking your hand because you've been picking your nose."

In practice, hold your tongue, shake the guys hand as you would any other, and if it bothers you that much, ask them to point you to the bathroom straight afterwards.